# How do I fix the applet exceptions on new Tomcat install (with Apache)?

Tags: permissions, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I got my Tomcat install to work and now I can receive JSP generated HTML web pages.  However, my applet, that works in 'appletViewer' is throwing exceptions.  I suspect one of two area for problems in my setup / configuration:

- path I am storing my applet files (.java, .class and .jar)
- proper reference to the java libraries for the browser (renderImage, event-pump, etc.)
- permissions

I reviewed the catalina.policy file and restarted tomcat with the -security (on windows using the service manager).  I am getting 404 stating that it cannot find the files -- but they are in the path shown in the log, therefore, it leads me to think it is not permissible.

JSP snippet:

```
// Form for submitting email to support.
<applet name="mymail" code="MyMail" codebase="/" archive="mystuff.jar" width=280 height=140>
</applet>
```

Logging error (removed timestamp and IP):

```
"GET /myapp/MyMail.class HTTP/1.1" 404 221
```

All the other resources are getting 200 (OK) and 304 (not modified).

Comment: Hey Zypher -- are you out there chilling?  I'll bet you know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: haha, yea i'm actually here tonight - that's what happens when you worked a 90 hour week, the woman is doing a girls night out and I'm on call. Are there any errors in the mod_jk log file? If you look at the security log do you see any failed audit entries for that file? I'll favorite this and check back tomorrow when i've had less beer and more sleep.

Comment: You know what -- I am about 2 hours shy of an all-nighter, so I will have to get the details tomorrow.  BTW - I don't know if I know where the security log is ... I have been observing the error output in the console.  As for mod_jk.log, it is all new to me, I will have to make a clean run to unclutter my other activity.

Comment: Sorry ment the say "Windows Security Log"

Comment: have you checked the `codebase` parameter?

Comment: yes, I was able to change code base to different values and the log entry changed accordingly to clearly 'invalid' locations.  When I put the path "/", the error changed to 404 (I forget the previous 305? 503?).  I have switched to other tasks and put this on the back-burner unless I stumble upon the answer.

Window Security Log is clean -- normal login/off and some "privileged" logins for my admin accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work tonight -- only three weeks later:(  ... the problem was really looking like permissions, security, etc. to access the .jar / .class files that are being referenced.  I needed to add the following statement to my `httpd.conf` file:

```
JkMount /*.class myworker1
```